# Using pytorch models in Swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, pytorch

I have trained a model in pytorch and converted it so that it is suitable for use in Swift. I followed pytorch documentation to create the iOS but I ran into a problem since I'm a total newbie in Swift. The app currently can run but the model output results are wrong. I suspect the problem is in this part

```swift
guard let outputs = module.predict(image: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(&pixelBuffer)) else {
            return
        }
        let zippedResults = zip(labels.indices, outputs)
        let sortedResults = zippedResults.sorted { $0.1.floatValue > $1.1.floatValue }.prefix(3)
```

I am unsure what is happening in the last line of code.

How would the following python code translate into swift?

```py
prediction = model(img)
pred_label = torch.softmax(prediction, dim=1).argmax(dim=1)

return pred_label
```

Comment: Did you exported model into .mlmodel format